# Ich verstehe ein Nomen eines Satzes nicht, bitte um Hilfe

Tags: sentence-structure, grammatical-case

[image: Foto vom problematischen Satz]

> Konsequenz war eine Bedingung richtigen, logischen Denkens, und wo
> immer in den unterschiedlichen philosophischen Theorien der Tradition
> deren Anfänge lagen, die Folgerungen wurden nicht willkürlich gezogen,
> sondern unter dem Druck, überzeugen, Beweise liefern, sich für den
> eingeschlagenen Weg rechtfertigen zu müssen.
> Wenn der Anfang einer Philosophie im eigenen Erleben, im Selbstgefühl
> lag, wie ließ sich dann ihre Dringlichkeit beweisen? Die drei
> Einzelkämpfer überließen sich der Leidenschaft, der Kunst der
> Darstellung, der Rhetorik des Herzens, so, wie ein Liebhaber seinem
> Liebesgeständnis **Druck** nicht durch Argumente, sondern durch Stil,
> durch Eigenart und Vehemenz die nötige Verführungskraft verleiht.
> — Eberhard Rathgeb, 「Die Entdeckung des Selbst」, 1. Auflage (2022), Seite 14.

Ich kann das fett markierte Nomen "Druck" nicht verstehen. Vielleicht könnte es mir beim Verstehen helfen, wenn Sie folgende Fragen beantworten. Zusätzliche Erklärungen bzw. Tipps sind auch herzlich willkommen. Ich bin dankbar dafür.

Kann man die Möglichkeit ausschließen, dass das fett markierte Nomen "Druck" hier fälschlich steht? Z.B. Fehler vom Autor, Fehler der Redaktion usw.

Wenn ja:

1. Ist das Nomen "Druck" Akkusativobjekt vom Verb "verleihen"? Wenn nicht, was ist der Kasus von dem "Druck"?
2. Könnten Sie bitte den Satz so umschreiben, dass er grammatikalisch einfacher wird?

---

Hinzugefügt am 16.06.2023: 
Ich habe den Verlag gebeten, den Satz zu überprüfen und ggf. den Autor zu fragen, und eine Antwort vom Lektorat bekommen:

> Das Wort „Druck“ ist an dieser Stelle kein Fehler, sondern vom Autor
> so gewollt, aber vielleicht etwas missverständlich in der
> Formulierung.
>
> Da es im vorhergehenden Abschnitt um den Druck ging, unter dem die
> drei Philosophen Schopenhauer, Kierkegaard & Nietzsche standen, mit
> ihren neuen philosophischen Ansichten zu überzeugen, wiederholt der
> Autor nachfolgend diesen Begriff.
>
> Zum besseren Verständnis wäre hier vielleicht eine etwas andere
> Formulierung mit dem Begriff „Nachdruck“ besser gewesen oder die
> Verwendung eines zusätzlichen Artikel „den Druck“.
>
> Die drei Philosophen versuchten also durch Leidenschaft, Kunst der
> Darstellung und Rhetorik des Herzens zu überzeugen – so, wie ein
> Liebhaber in seinem Liebesgeständnis nicht durch (Nach)druck nur mit
> seinen Argumenten verführen will, sondern durch Stil, Eigenart und
> Vehemenz.

Den Inhalt verstehe ich durchaus. Ich bin aber immer noch nicht vom Gedanken losgeworden, dass der Satz grammatisch falsch formuliert sein müsste.

> … so, wie ein Liebhaber einem Liebesgeständnis Druck **nicht** durch
> Argumente, **sondern** durch Still (…) die nötige Verführungskraft
> verleiht.

Was hier durch "nicht" verneint wird, ist "durch Argumente". Das "Druck" wird nicht verneint und daher bleibt das Akkusativobjekt. Aber danach tritt ein anderes Akkusativobjekt, "Verführungskraft", auf. Das sieht für mich falsch aus. Ich denke, dass man das Objekt "Druck" verneinen soll, um ein anderes Objekt, "Verführungskraft", einzusetzen. Die Alternative, die RHa in seiner/ihrer Antwort geschrieben hat, scheint mich grammatisch richtig. Da ist das "Druck" verneint; also es heißt so: "nicht (…) Druck, sondern (…) Verführungskraft".

Aber ich soll vielleicht eine neue Frage stelle, um diese Sache zu besprechen. Hier an dieser Stelle bedanke ich mich nur für alle bisherige Antworten.

Comment: Was ist denn Deine eigene Analyse oder Verständnis des Satzes und damit des Wortes? Was exakt ist an dem Wort unklar?
Und bitte schreibe Text als Text und binde ihn nicht als Bild ein (außer es geht um das Erkennen von Handschriften o.ä.)

Comment: @planetmaker Wie du aufgefordert hast, habe ich gerade den Text abgetippt. Meine Analyse oder Verständnis des Satzes: Es ist eher eine Vermutung. Ich vermutete, dass das Nomen "Druck" aus Versehen da gesetzt wäre. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob es tatsächlich ein Fehler ist oder ob ich den Satz nicht verstehe.

Comment: Hier scheint sich tatsächlich jemand im Wirwarr des eigenen Satzes verirrt zu haben. Am Ende bleibt immer ein Akkusativobjekt übrig....

Comment: @tofro Danke für den Kommentar!

Comment: Autor, Werk, Auflage, Seitenzahl der Quelle wären noch wünschenswert.

Comment: @userunknown Eberhard Rathgeb, 「Die Entdeckung des Selbst」, 1. Auflage (2022), Seite 14.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Der Satz kann (mit etwas geänderter Reihenfolge und Ergänzungen in eckigen Klammern) so gelesen werden

> ... so, wie ein Liebhaber seinem Liebesgeständnis nicht durch Argumente  Druck [verleiht], sondern [ihm] durch Stil, durch Eigenart und Vehemenz die nötige Verführungskraft verleiht.

So ergibt es einigermaßen Sinn. Ob es stilistisch gelungen ist, darüber kann man streiten.

Comment: Das ist in der Tat (theoretisch) eine grammatisch sinnvolle Interpretation. Ich kann mir aber nicht vorstellen, dass jemand tatsächlich einen solchen Satz schreiben würde.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort!

Comment: Eine zusätzliche Frage: Könnte es Ihrer Meinung nach sein, dass der Satz aus Versehen so geschrieben wurde? Oder halten Sie es für wahrscheinlicher, dass der Autor absichtlich so geschrieben hat? 

Hintergrund meiner Frage: Als Deutschlerner möchte ich wissen, ob ich den Satz als einen mögliches Satz annehmen soll oder als einen falschen –falsch in dem Sinne, dass keiner absichtlich so schreiben würde– Satz verwerfen soll.

Comment: Ich halte es durchaus für möglich, dass der Autor sich absichtlich so seltsam ausgedrückt hat. Dass sich die Reihenfolge bei "... durch Argumente Druck / durch Eigenart ... die nötige Verführungskraft" umkehrt, könnte ein beabsichtigter sog. Chiasmus sein, ein altes Stilmittel.

Comment: An dem Satz "wie ein Liebhaber seinem Liebesgeständnis Druck verleiht" ist nichts auszusetzen. Erst der Einschub "nicht durch ..." kann den Leser verwirren. Aber der Verfasser hat das mit Sicherheit nicht versehentlich so gemacht.

Comment: @PaulFrost Danke für den Kommentar. Sie sagen, "mit Sicherheit nicht versehentlich"… Einige Anderen waren der Meinung, dass der Satz sicherlich fälschlich geschrieben worden sei. Offensichtlich gibt es krasse Meinungsunterschiede auch unter Muttersprachlern.  Pfuh, schwierig!

Comment: @Bandabi Bei sprachlichen Themen gibt es häufig unterschiedliche Auffassungen. Gerade die deutsche Sprache hat auch einige Besonderheiten, die lange und verschachtelte Sätze ermöglicht. Manche Autoren reizen das aus, manchmal kann dann der Leser darüber "stolpern".

Comment: Auch wenn es ein absichtlicher Chiasmus ist, müsste es sinnvollerweise "**nicht Druck** durch Argumente, sondern durch Stil, durch Eigenart und Vehemenz die nötige Verführungskraft" heißen, statt "**Druck nicht** durch Argumente...". Beabsichtigt, aber verstolpert, würde ich sagen.

Comment: @HalvarF Ich bin Ihrer Meinung.

Answer (score 3):

Der Satz ist definitiv falsch.

Entweder "Druck" oder "die nötige Verführungskraft" gehört aus dem Satz weg. Eines davon ist das Akkusativobjekt, das andere kann es dann nicht mehr sein.

Grundsätzlich denke ich aber schon, dass man "Druck verleihen" sagen kann; man findet jedenfalls einige Beispiele davon per Websuche. Es fiele mir als Muttersprachler jedenfalls nicht als offensichtlicher Fehler auf.

Comment: Danke für Ihre Antwort! Noch eine zusätzliche Frage: 
Würden Sie aus dem Satz lieber "Druck" entfernen oder "die Verführungskraft"? Oder anders gefragt, denken Sie, dass das "Druck" fälschlich gesetzt wurde oder "die Verführungskraft"?

Comment: @Bandabi Sofern nicht die Antwort des Benutzers "RHa" tatsächlich richtig ist, schätze ich, dass der Satz ursprünglich mit "Druck" geschrieben wurde, sich dann der Verfasser umentschieden hat auf "Verführungskraft", aber vergessen hat, "Druck" wieder zu entfernen; oder evtl. umgekehrt. Ich weiß es nicht, ich kann nicht die Gedanken anderer Leute lesen.

Comment: Ja klar, dass man die Gedanken anderer nicht lesen kann. :) Ich wollte nur Ihre Meinung hören. Vielen Dank für Ihre Antwort.

Comment: Ohne die Antworten zu lesen bin ich zu Deinem Schluss gekommen, dass der Autor umformuliert hat, und ihm der "Druck" beim Korrigieren entgangen ist. RHas Interpretation, auf die ich nicht gekommen war, scheint mir aber einen Deut schlüssiger, wobei ich jedoch die Formulierung "(Sie) überließen sich (...) der Rhetorik des Herzens, so, wie ein Liebhaber seinem Liebesgeständnis nicht Druck durch Argumente, sondern durch Stil (...) die nötige Verführungskraft verleiht", also mit "nicht" vor "Druck", statt danach, sprachlich runder empfunden hätte.

Answer (score 1):

> Kann man die Möglichkeit ausschließen, dass das fett markierte Nomen "Druck" hier fälschlich steht?

Die Möglichkeit kann man nicht aussschließen, ich halte sie sogar für ziemlich wahrscheinlich. Wenn man das Wort "Druck" an der hervorgehobenen Stelle einfach weglässt, ergibt der Satz deutlich mehr Sinn. Das Objekt des Satzes ist "Liebesgeständnis" (im Dativ), das Verb "verleiht" bezieht sich darauf, und das Nomen "Druck" scheint mir versehentlich dorthin geraten zu sein.

Vielleicht hatte der der Autor ja den Begriff "Ausdruck" im Kopf, aber dann hätte er allenfalls "... durch Stil, Ausdruck, Eigenart ..." schreiben können.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Früher hat mir jemand, der auch Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernt, gesagt, dass das "Druck" ein Akkusativobjekt vom Verb "verleihen" sein sollte. Ich war aber nicht überzeugt, weil das Verb ein anderes eindeutigeres Objekt, "Verführungskraft", hat. Ein Verb könnte ja mehr als ein Objekt haben, aber dafür sah die Position vom "Druck" komisch aus…. Meine Vermutung ist also nicht komplett daneben! Ich bin froh.

Comment: @Bandabi, tatsächlich stand das in meiner Antwort. Die habe ich jedoch gelöscht, weil ich das Akkusativobjekt *die nötige Verführungskraft* völlig übersehen hatte und von der Wendung *einer Sache Druck/Ausdruck verleihen* ausgegangen war.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich Oh, ich habe deine Antwort zwar gesehen, aber in meinem Kommentar nicht deine Antwort gemeint. Das hat mir ein koreanischer Lerner gesagt. :) Danke, dass du für mich eine Antwort verfasst hast.

Comment: Man könnte das auch als zwei Akkusativobjekte lesen, oder? Er verleiht seinem Liebesgeständnis erstens Druck (nicht durch Argumente, sondern durch Stil) und zweitens die nötige Verführungskraft (durch Eigenart und Vehemenz).

Comment: @DonHolgo: das müsste man dann aber auch schon so formulieren, wie du das jetzt getan hast.

Comment: "Vielleicht hatte der der Autor ja den Begriff 'Ausdruck' im Kopf": Oder aber "**Nachdruck**" (d.h. besondere Eindringlichkeit), den *der Liebhaber seinem Liebesgeständnis durch Argumente bzw. Stil verleihen* will. Vgl. mit "Verführungskraft".

Comment: Ich lese es so (und habe RHa auch so verstanden), dass sowohl Mittel (Argumente/Stil usw.), als auch Ziel (Druck/Verführungskraft) gewechselt werden. Stilistisch gelungen ist es m.E. so oder so nicht.